# Notificacion con javascript en c#

Tags: javascript, c#, notificaciones

mi problema es el siguiente, tengo una función de notificaciones con toast en javascript, pero mi problema es que quiero que se muestre solo despues de un proceso desde el backend y no con solo actualizar la pagina.

Este es mi codigo javascript

```
<script>

$(function showContent() {


    Command: toastr["success"]("Datos guardados con exito!", "Validando")

    toastr.options = {
        "closeButton": false,
        "debug": false,
        "newestOnTop": false,
        "progressBar": true,
        "positionClass": "toast-top-right",
        "preventDuplicates": true,
        "onclick": null,
        "showDuration": "300",
        "hideDuration": "1000",
        "timeOut": "5000",
        "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
        "showEasing": "swing",
        "hideEasing": "linear",
        "showMethod": "fadeIn",
        "hideMethod": "fadeOut"

    }

});
```

Si necesitan alguna información más con gusto edito la publicación

Comment: revisa sobre signalR, te ayudará a hacer sistemas en tiempo real :D Por otro lado, aquí tienes una lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo revisare en seguida

Comment: Ya lo revise e igual la lectura, creo que no me exprese bien, solo espero que me puedan ayudar en cuanto la función javascript, no del backend ya lo tengo, solo quiero saber que le puedo mover a ese codigo que tengo para que no se ejecute al cargar la pagina, de ante mano muchas gracias

Comment: Como lo esta haciendo en el backend ? Con signal R, con socket.io o con SQLDependency ???Como lo esta haciendo en el servidor para ayudarle en el front.

Comment: string javaScript = "Notificacion();";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", javaScript, true);

Comment: Asi es como llamo a la función de javascript desde el backend

Comment: El problema es la logica, lo que haces es que al cargar la pagina (por cualquier medio) y al terminar ejecutas el Javascript, entonces mi pregunta sería ¿como sabe tu backend que es una recarga de pagina o un envio de datos valido?